# tomcat7 deployment using tomcat7 maven plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, tomcat7, m2eclipse

I am trying to use the eclipse maven plugin but when using the command:

tomcat7:deploy I am getting build successful with lots of html output explaining about adding users, I have added the user to tomcat with only manager-script.
and added that to the user of settings.xml in maven.

What am I doing wrong?

From the tomcat logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2012:23:50:34 +0100] "PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2F HTTP/1.1" 401 2486
```

my cofigurations

pom.xml

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <server>tomcat_7</server>
                <port>8180</port>
                <path>/</path>
                <url>http://localhost:8180/manager/text</url>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

settings.xml

```
<server>
  <id>tomcat_7</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>secret</password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<user username="admin" password="secret" roles="manager-script" />
```

Comment: It looks the authentication does not work based on the 401 error code? Have you checked that just by using a browser?

Comment: I have tried using the browser to visit /manager/text and get a message saying fail. Using the tomcat plugin without using eclipse, but only using the command line the deployment works fine. Any ideas why its not working through eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I managed to fix the problem.

I checked where the eclipse thought the maven settings.xml file was. This was the main problem, there was no settings.xml file therefore no authentication. I coppied the file to the path specified in eclipse.

The build is now successful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<server>tomcat_7</server>
```

and add

```
<username>admin</username>
<password>s3cret</password>
```

to rule out any maven settings.xml issues.